# Javascript null or empty control does not work

Tags: javascript, null

I open this subject for second time.

However there is no solution.

Below code does not work. I can enter empty(Space) value.

```
var veri = {
YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#YeniMusteriAdiTextbox_I').val(),
};
if (!veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox) {
alert("Customer name can not be empty!");
}
```

Comment: Don't open new identical questions

Comment: @mplungjan it's not strictly identical - the answers to the other question (from which this code came) failed to mention the need to `trim` the input to remove leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: Regardless, the correct approach is clearly to edit the other question.  There is no interaction from the OP on the other question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var veri = {
YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#YeniMusteriAdiTextbox_I').val(),
};
if (veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox.trim()=="" || veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox==undefined) {
alert("Customer name can not be empty!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Amit , your code works!

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the value to remove leading and trailing white space:

```
var veri = {
    YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#YeniMusteriAdiTextbox_I').val().trim()
};
```

The `.trim` method doesn't exist on some older browsers, there's a shim to add it at the above MDN link.  Since you're using jQuery you could also use `$.trim`.

Comment: So answer the other question and leave this one to rot - and use $.trim() to not have to use the shim

Comment: @mplungjan in general I recommend using shims instead of adhoc library replacements for "standard" ES5 functions so as to encourage use of those standard APIs as and when they're supported "out of the box" by newer browsers.

Comment: If you already use jQuery there is absolutely no need to add a shim in my opinion. jQuery already uses .trim if available and a shim if not

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all the whitespaces to achieve that

```
var veri = {
    YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#YeniMusteriAdiTextbox_I').val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
};
if (!veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox) {
    alert("Customer name can not be empty!");
}
```

**UPD: Some additional information**

Your object

```
var veri = {
    YeniMusteriEkleTextBox: $('#YeniMusteriAdiTextbox_I').val(),
};
```

has a comma after last key-value pair. This can cause an error in IE.

Right ways is:

```
var obj = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2' // no comma after last pair
}
```

Comment: and what it whitespace _within_ the string is legal?

Comment: @Alnitak String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');}; Same regex :) although You are right, it might be useful to add the .trim() method

Comment: Which jQuery does for free. $.trim()

Comment: When I wrote that comment it wasn't the same regex - you had `/\s/g`

Comment: @Alnitak yes I've changed that without mentioning, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if (veri.YeniMusteriEkleTextBox!='') {
alert("Customer name can not be empty!");
}
```

Comment: That would be very silly unlesss you meant to use it as a debug to see if the statement was executed at all